# how to create a invoice sheet in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, invoice

I'm using oracle Apex 22.2 to build an app to manage records for a company and I need to print an invoice as in the image below. and I need to use Unicode characters on the invoice. how can I create a page with an invoice as below? what region and items should I use? [the way I need the invoice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEi5x.png)

I'm new to oracle apex and I tried using the static content region for the task but got stuck.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typically you don't print the actual html page as invoice. You can use the native printing but that doesn't really print nice templates like you need. Google "Oracle APEX printing solutions" for alternatives. Note that most of them are payed solutions.

Comment: there are several tools. Oracle BI Publisher, Apache FOP, Jasper Reports, Office Print, etc... you can use anyone of those.